# Atajo de teclado global en vb.net

Tags: vb.net, windows

banda, ando jugando con eventos en VB.NET, especialmente con los atajos de teclado, he visto que se puede programar una accion determinada si se presiona un tecla específica, pero lamentablemente sólo funciona en el ambito de la aplicación, es decir si presiono DEL fuera del ambito de la aplicacion no ejecuta nada la aplicación. El foco debe estar en la aplicación para que funcionen los atajos de teclado que se le programó. Algúna forma para que cuando presione en cualquier lugar de windows (CTRL + q)/ DEL ejecute un hola mundo de mi aplicación en VB.NET?

He probado con este metodo pero, solo funciona cuando el foco esta en la aplicacion VB.NET

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Delete Then
  Msgbox ("Hola mundo!")
End If
```